# Primitive comparation doesnt work in php

Tags: php

I've got simple code (strings are cyrillic):

```
<?php

$main_menu = [
    'Главная' => ['index.php' => 'fa-home'],
    'Загрузить файл' => ['upload.php' => 'fa-cloud-upload'],
    "Статистика" => ['statistics.php' => 'fa-bar-chart'],
];

$submenu = [
    "Cтатистика" => [ 'Продажи товара' => 'товар' ],
];

foreach($main_menu as $name => $val){
    foreach($submenu as $sname => $sval){
        echo "$name == $sname <br>";
        if($name == $sname){
            print_r($sval);
        }
    }

}
```

But it doesnt work. Why does it not compare right? At the same time in_array() and array_search() doesnt work correctly too. There is no such a problem with strings.

Comment: [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: englisch please

Comment: Please translate your question to English or try http://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Why so downvote?

Comment: what in echo? user var_dump better

Comment: There's no diffrence, the problem is that comparing doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because your 2 strings are not identical. One starts with `0x43 0xD1` (`Статистика`) and the other with `0xD0 0xA1` (`Cтатистика`)

Comment: @Rizier123, how did you found out this?

Comment: Put them in a hex editor and look at them

Comment: Yeah, your right, thanks a lot!